# How do I convert the object passed in to an array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-in-loop

```
function objectToArray (object) {
   var array = [];
   var str = "";
   for (var key in object) {
       array.push(key);
       array.push(object[key]);
       if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
             str += key + " is "  + object[key] + "";
       }
     }
   console.log(array);
 }
 objectToArray({name: "Marcia", age: 101});
```

The output is `[ 'name', 'Marcia', 'age', 101 ]` and I need it to be `["name is Marcia", "age is 101"]`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of this:

```
   array.push(key);
   array.push(object[key]);
   if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
         str += key + " is "  + object[key] + "";
   }
```

You want this:

```
   if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
         array.push( key + " is "  + object[key] + "" );
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

@VoteyDisciple has correctly pointed out where you went wrong with your approach. An alternate (shorter) way to implement your function is:

```js
function objectToArray (object) {
  return Object.keys(object).map(function (key) {
    return key + " is " + object[key];
  });
 }

var arr = objectToArray({name: "Marcia", age: 101});
console.log(arr);
```